# How can I choose a music player?

Tags: applications, samsung-galaxy-s-3, music-player

I am looking for a music player for my android device which has a number of specific features (such as having a play queue, lock screen controls, etc.) I am finding it difficult because there are lots of music players out there and they don't list all of their features "on the box".

For example, *Double Twist* has an "add to play queue" option, but it doesn't say so "on the box", so I had to download it and try it to know. I was wondering if there were any resources out there which provide complete feature lists or some other means of helping me find what I want.

Comment: A lot of apps never show their full features. But how about if you do a Google Search for Android music player reviews, My Dear Watson? [ignore the Watson; I'm trying to see what unlocks the Watson hat]

Comment: @geff_chang Edit a post to get that hat !!

Comment: @Sid Thanks for the tip. It took me a while to understand what it meant. I get it now. :)

Comment: @shawn What is wrong with your stock player? *play queue, lock screen controls, etc...* are there.

Comment: @Sid I didn't see a play queue in the stock player. And in any case, I don't believe you can edit meta data either.

Comment: @geff_chang Yes I tried google but haven't found much, hence the question.

Comment: @Shawn Checkout the answer

Answer (score 3):

This is the method I use for finding important apps which have to fit certain requirements:

1. Make a list of all the features you want.
2. Have some music in the standard music folder which the standard music app uses. Don't have too much music as it may take a new app a long time to read it all.
3. Find an article which compares popular music players like ["10 best android music players"](http://www.techradar.com/news/phone-and-communications/mobile-phones/10-best-android-music-players-1114284). Popular ones will be most likely to have lots of features.
4. Download the music apps mentioned in the articles.
5. Start it and test it to see if it has the features on your list. Keep a record of the ones that meet most of your requirements, as there is a chance you might not find exactly what you want.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question but +1 for the first suggestion from your link which has most of the features I was looking for (n7player)

Answer (score 1):

The app best suits for you is **Sony Walkman Player**

Here are the download links.

> [Walkman.apk](http://www.mediafire.com/?ajalsjbbpp2sp41)
>   [Visualizerpack.apk](http://www.mediafire.com/?c9nwft2ar3ad2n0)

---

All the features you want can be found here.

- Have a play queue
  [image: Play Queue]
- Have lock screen controls
  [image: LSC]
- Visualizer mode.
- Edit metadata
- And many more.
  [image: More Features]

Simply install it and try it out.

Comment: Looks wonderful. Just one small problem. When I play songs,  no sound is produced. At all. Makes it kind of useless. I suppose it's not compatible with my device for some reason (Galaxy S 3)

Comment: that's odd. try turning off the equalizer or try different equalizer settings.

Comment: Not working. I just installed n7player and i'm getting the same problem (no sound).

Comment: Then check sounds with your stock player. And go to settings > sound > volume. Try to test speakers with [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35758/23379)

Comment: The sound works fine in the stock player, with double twist, with flixster, for phone calls, etc. And the speaker test worked too

Comment: then you may want to ask a seperate question stating your new problem with reference to this one. so tuat the other S3 users can help you. most probably you're facing a compatibility issue. post a link if you're gonna do it. good luck!! (I'm really sad :( that you can't use walkman)

Comment: What do you know, the sound works now. The Queue track features doesn't though... http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35982/why-do-i-get-error-cannot-play-track-from-the-walkman-app-when-i-use-the-queu