# How to view the android service menu (secret menu)?

Tags: settings, dialer-codes

Most of the mobile manufacturers include a hidden service menu in their mobile handsets. These menus allow users (or developers) to access some technical information and service personnel to access service details etc.

Is there a similar service menu for android devices and What can I do with that menu?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, there *is* a menu available for handsets running android OS. To get the menu, go to your stock phone app and type the following.

> **`**#*#7378423#*#*`**

It is simply `*#*#SERVICE#*#*`

---

There are many things you can do in this menu.

- View service information
- Check service settings
- Carryout service tests
- Reset customization settings

Some of these items may differ from handset to handset. These are the typical menu items available. This menu comes handy when checking the total call timer (in `service tests`), Rooting status check (in `Service info -> Configuration`), etc.

Answer (score 30):

As the *How* has already been explained, you might want to have the *What* as well:

There are several lists on the internet (just google for "secret codes") with many of those codes. Not all of them work on all phones (some are device or manufacturer specific), but many are common to all Android devices (and some times even to all smartphones). I won't list all of them here, but a few more important to be known include...

```
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────┬───────────────────────┐
| Code                                             | Description           |
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────┤
| *#0011#                                          | GSM Infos             |
| *#0228#                                          | Battery Infos         |
| **05*<PUK>*<new PIN>*<new PIN for confirmation># | Unlock PIN            |
| *#*#0588#*#*                                     | Test Proximity sensor |
| *#06#                                            | Show IMEI             |
| *#*#1234#*#*                                     | Firmware Info         |
| *135#                                            | Show your phone number|
| *#*#197328640#*#*                                | Service Menu          |
| *#*#7378423#*#* (*#*#SERVICE#*#*)                | Service Menu          |
| *#*#2432546#*#* (*#*#CHECKIN#*#*)                | Check for OTA Updates |
| *2767*3855#                                      | Factory Format        |
| #31#<phoneNumber>                                | anonymous call        |
| *#*#3264#*#*                                     | RAM Test              |
| *#*#4636#*#* (*#*#INFO#*#*)                      | System Infos          |
| *#*#7594#*#*                                     | Customize PowerButton |
| *#*#7780#*#*                                     | Factory Reset         |
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────┴───────────────────────┘
```

Use at your own risk -- some options might prove dangerous (e.g. the factory format) -- especially if you don't know what they are supposed to mean, think twice or better avoid the option.

Comment: Getting good at ascii drawing xD +1 from me... _o/

Comment: Why most of them are not working on my Xperia Neo V running CM10?

Comment: I don't know -- I didn't try all of them on all devices there are. I'm aware that not all of them work on all phones (as I wrote) -- but I cannot say which ones work on which phones, sorry...

Answer (score 8):

Go to your phone dialer
[image: Dialer]
and enter these codes (they work in my Samsung Galaxy Nexus, Jelly Bean 4.2.1):

- ***'Testing'*** menu: `*#*#4636#*#*` (the same as `*#*#INFO#*#*`)
  [image: 'Testing' menu]
- IMEI number: `*#06#`
  [image: IMEI]

Additionaly check out the page [Secret codes for Android](https://sites.google.com/site/barbarahohensee/secret-codes-for-android), full of codes (some of them didn't work in my phone) and screenshots

**Note: Please be *extremely* careful with the options, because they're not intended to be messing with them.**