# People can't hear me on my Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, calls, microphone, mute

When I send or receive a call, the person on the other side can't hear me.

Sometimes, the microphone goes mute during the call. But when I check if the phone is on mute, but it isn't. It happens randomly.

The microphone seems to be OK, and I think this is probably a software problem. Would upgrading the OS (from ICS to JB) fix this?

Comment: Check if you have call recording software installed - or something in that line. I once wasted my time with such a problem and later found to be due to a call recording software.

Comment: I have never installed a call recording software. I just noticed some apps that is in execution and could use microphone. Like SVoice.

Comment: Go to your [service menu](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35758/23379) and check whether your microphone is fine. (this is the best way to do a service check). If yes, it is better to try upgrading the OS

Comment: I haven't found the right code for my phone. *#*#197328640#*#* and *#*#7378423#*#* don't work. What should I use?

Comment: I think it is always best to update your phone when possible. If it is a software problem, it will probably be fixed in these updates. If an update didn't fix it, you should try contacting Samsung support for this (don't root your phone if you want Samsung to help you though :-) )

Answer (score 3):

I  was a having the same problem, look next to the charging port (that would be to your right) there a tiny hole CLEAN IT OUT it is blocked. I used a sewing needle to clean it out. After that people on the other side could hear me again. That hole used for talking.

Comment: I think that my problem is a little bit different. More likely a software problem that a real hardware problem. I stopped the battery saving app, hope that this resolve.