# Get the first time Android device launched or used

Tags: call-history

I am about to buy a new nexus 4, the seller claims its never been used.

Is there any guaranteed way to check the mobile first time use?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Simply go to the handset [service menu](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/35758/23379) and check the total call timer. Simple and easy.

Comment: Unfortunately service does not work on galaxy nexus

Comment: What do you mean *does not work*? There are several methods in the question. None of them work?

Comment: is "total call timer" is totally guaranteed? can it be reset in anyway? **does not work** means when I insert the code on the dialer simply the code reset to empty and nothing happen.

Comment: *total call timer* can be guaranteed. are you using it with a SIM inserted?

Comment: yes absolutely with SIM inserted

Comment: can you try ##786# ?

Comment: *Connection problem or Invalid MMI code*

Comment: @Sid **What about factory reset?** - Easy for the seller to do just that prior to selling *used* Nexus! There may be clues lying around, possibly a `recovery.log` within  recovery partition... as for the dial code that looks wrong!