# How can I check the firmware version of my ONDA V712?

Tags: device-firmware

Is there an easy way to check the firmware version (not Android version)?

Comment: How about in `Settings > About Phone`? My Galaxy S2 has it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either [the way geff_chang suggested](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36674/how-can-i-check-the-firmware-version-of-my-onda-v712#comment47911_36674) or [use android service menus](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/35758/23379)

In the service menu, it is located at `Software info -> Phone info`

You can always use [third party apps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.electricsheep.asi) as well.

Comment: It's a tablet so the service menu won't work

Comment: @Casebash see the edit.

Comment: That app certainly gives very detailed information, but I can't see the firmware version anywhere

Comment: go to app -> select system tab -> click Buildinfos The firmware version is what's called as the `Id`