# How can one know if one's battery is damaged

Tags: battery-life

What are the signs of a damaged or completely drained battery for Samsung Galaxy Note II? The battery displays it is empty and yet does not charge. It does not power the phone either. Am confused

Answer (score 1):

You can check the the battery status using the [service menu](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/35758/23379) of your android device.

You can see the current battery level there. The device suggests whether or not to change the battery.