# How to find the unboxing date of an Android device?

Tags: operating-system

Someone told me that he has opened a phone only 4 days ago, but by the look of it, it is not less than a month.

When trying to buy a used phone, is there any way to check how long this phone is in use? Or the date when this phone is turned on the first time? Or the time of unboxing? Or the time of the first usage?

Comment: Define *not less than a month*?

Comment: @t0mm13b "at least a month" is the usual definition.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply go the [Service menu](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/35758/23379) of your phone and see the total call time which is very hard to reset. By that, you can *assume* how long it has been used.

As of Android 4.3 Jellybean, that is the **best** you can get.

Answer (score 1):

This answer was given by [izzy](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/16575/izzy) on [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/59243/17770). I won't take credit for it so do not upvote this answer. please go to [izzy's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/59252/17770) and upvote there.

- with your Google account's credentials, log in to the [Google Dashboard](https://www.google.com/settings/dashboard)
- Scroll to the section labeled "Android" and expand it (by clicking its title / the LGM [little green man])
- Check the entry for the device you want to know the date for

Answer (score 0):

1. Checking for the timestamps on various folders in internal storage.

   Android folders might be created at the time of ROM installation (device manufacturing), but many app folders are created on the date of activation. Firmware updates don't generally remove this, though factory reset might. However, the issue is checking the correct folders which change from device to device, and a factory reset might also reset these dates.
2. Checking the age of the battery.

   Counting cycles of battery use could be a rough way. Even checking the absolute battery capacity relative to original battery capacity could give an idea. However, if the battery is changed, this fails irrespective of the age.

Answer (score -1):

Another option to find the date the device was physically built:

Settings (scroll to bottom) > About phone (scroll all the way down to the bottom again) > build date

Just checked this out on my phone. I unboxed the phone in November 2013, and the phone shows build date from September 2013, so that seems to be it.

model: Droid MAXX

Android version: 4.4

Comment: That's the date the ROM was compiled, not the date the device was  physically manufactured. Mine, for example, has a build date of May 5, 2014, but I purchased it in late 2013 (so clearly it was not physically built in 2014).