# Why do I get `Error Cannot play track` from the Walkman app when I use the `Queue track` feature?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

I'm using the Walkman app which I downloaded from http://www.mediafire.com/?ajalsjbbpp2sp41 and the `Queue track` feature doesn't work. When I try it, I get the following error message:

```
Error

Cannot play track
```

Is there a solution for this type of thing?

Note: This is on a Samsung Galaxy S3

Comment: You get this error when the app cannot find your trwck in your memory card or the file is corrupted. try queing up different set of files from different locations (different folders)

Comment: All my music is in the same folder, and I've tried many songs and none work, even though they all work in other players.

Comment: now I'm running outta options. try this. remove the app, reboot, copy a new mp3 to a seperate folder, reinstall the app and play again.

Comment: How did it go? Still the problem is there?

Comment: Oh, sorry for the radio silence. Actually I lost my phone... So I don't know. Thanks for trying! I'll write back if I ever try it on my new phone (not an S3)