# How to auto-restart media playback when connecting the headphones

Tags: media-player, headphones

I am looking for a way to restart media playback where it was stopped as soon as I reconnect the headphones. I know there was a media player with this feature (I cannot remember which one), but I did not like its way of managing/playing the playlists.

I am running Android 4.0.3 on an HTC One V, using the default media player that is installed on it.

Comment: I took the freedom to rephrase your question for two reasons: 1) "is there an app for X" is off topic according to our [FAQ], and 2) your question looked like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/16575) (you don't want another media player, but that feature to work ;) Feel free to correct if I did wrong.

Comment: Check the new answer. Hope it suits you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution for you would be to use [**Smart Connect Liveware™ Mgr**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware&hl=en).

[image: ScreenCap]

As you can see, you can set actions to start when you plug a device (headset, HDMI, charger, etc.) and actions to start when you unplug the device. I have a setting to start playing music when I connect my headphones and stop playing when I remove it. There are *many things* you can do with this.

The best part is that you can manage your music with your own music app! Simply create an event for actions to be done upon the connection pf a headphone and forget this app!

This was originally developed for Sony Xperia Handsets. But should work with any, which has a good hardware configuration [(src)](http://www.askmefast.com/CAN_I_INSTALL_SONY_SMARTWATCH_LIVEWARE_MANAGER_IN_SAMSUNG_GT5253-qna3740141.html#q1562633) and an OS higher that ICS (which you already have).

Comment: I installed it and it does not seem to be compatible with the built-in player in my HTC One V phone. The headphones connection is properly detected and triggers the action of starting it, but nothing sounds on it. I guess this is something specific to my player.

Comment: You can try different player apps. just add **start application** action to trigger and select your preffered app. [Sony walkman](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/35948/23379) is a good one.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way might be to use some headset controller like e.g. [JAYS Headset Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=se.jays.headsetcontrol) (there are plenty more on the playstore if this one doesn't work out for you -- I also had to try a few until I found the right one working smoothly with my headset).

Most of them allow you to define an app to be started as soon as the headset is connected (in your case, that would be the media player of your choice). Beside that, they give you the ability to control the media player via your 1-button-headset control: Tap once to play/pause (or accept a call), tap twice to skip forward a title (or reject a call), hold the button to increase volume, and much more.

**EDIT:** I see k3b and I both misunderstood your question as "start the player", while you were talking about "start playback". One app which can solve this is [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) (see their website for a free trial version). The *Tasker user manual* [mentions in the actions section](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/help/ah_index.html):

> **Media Control**
>   Send a command to a media playback application.
>
> Simulate Media Button: when selected, any media player which listens for Media Button events can be controlled. Without it, the only the Android system media player will respond.

So this should do what you want.

Comment: My headset is a cheapo one, with no button at all.Don't know whether this would work. I will try it.

Comment: In that case, maybe Llama is the better choice for you, as you can use its other features for added benefit. But of course you have the choice :)

Comment: I just see I mis-read your question: you don't want to *start* the mediaplayer, but *restart* playback. In this case, the headset control apps probably don't help, as they would just launch the app (not start the playback). Llama might indeed be able to solve this, if it can handle playback control.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this with free [kebab.Llama](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kebab.Llama&hl=en)

It is an event monitor that can do actions when an event on the phone happend.

You can configure that whenever the event "Headset-Connected" occours start the app musicplayer (or any other app you want)

Comment: I seem to have problems with it. I created the condition and action, but nothing seems to happen. I use the music player that is included with my cell phone, an HTC One V.

Comment: Looks like k3b also mis-understood your question as "start the player" instead of "starting playback"...