# How can I automatically correct tags of music files?

Tags: music, id3-tag

I've seen apps like Shazaam and TrackID, which can provide the Artist, Album etc. info, by recording a few seconds of a song from any source.
In my music gallery, there're lots of songs, with incorrect artist, albums or genre names. So is there a way that allows me to automatically correct these info, or at least fill up the missing info?

Comment: Preferably a free app, or a lower priced app will do. Or if there're any workaround to get this thing done, with existing music players.

Comment: Please note that app recommendations as such are off topic here according to our [FAQ].

Comment: Have you looked in the Play Store? What have you already tried. A key search term for you will be "ID3". Have you tried fixing the music tracks on your desktop machine using any of the many available tools that are out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use the Sony walkman app, that is the best solution for you. See the answer in [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/35709/23379). If that app is not compatible with your device, [Album Art Grabber](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.citc.aag) would be a good solution for you.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know walkman app can do this too. I actually have a Sony Xperia phone, so Walkman was already installed.

Answer (score 1):

[Music Tagger](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.deosapps.musictagger) from [Deos Apps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Deos+Apps) can do exactly what you're asking.

It can identify your files and download metadata and album art for them automatically.

> Music Tagger is a music tag editor that introduces automated features
>   like lyrics grabbing & album art grabbing to make the process of
>   tagging your song files quick and easy. Music Tagger also uses an
>   audio identification system to automatically identify and tag your
>   files individually or in batch. Album information is pulled from the
>   MusicBrainz database which can also be directly accessed and tag
>   information for each track downloaded and applied to files manually.
>   Music Tagger Editor is also capable of organising and renaming your
>   song files once they have been tagged.  Folders for artists and albums
>   can be created and files renamed based on renaming structure selected
>   from the given options.
>
> Music Tagger automatically updates the Media Store Database when
>   changes have been made to files to ensure changes reflect on all other
>   media applications. Please take note that some music players use their
>   own databases and may take longer to reflect changes to files, a
>   manual update may need to be invoked within the application if it is
>   possible.
>
> Music Tagger Currently supports the following file formats MP3, FLAC ,
>   M4A and MP4 audio files only

Comment: It always returns me "Auto tag failed"