# Corrupt album art

Tags: music-player, id3-tag, album-art

One of my albums has a corrupt album art and I can do nothing to fix it. The cover is stored as a file named folder.jpg in the audio files' folder. The picture looks fine when I open it with any picture viewer on my computer. But on my Android device it looks like a plain gray box with only a small part of the upper-left corner showing the actual picture.

I've deleted this picture and replaced it with a higher res one I found on the Internet (totally different source). The album art is still corrupt. I've deleted the album (audio + jpg files), rebooted the device, and copied it back. The album art is still corrupt. I've deleted any embedded album art in the MP3 files' tags using foobar2000 and MP3Tag. The album art is still corrupt. I've cleared the data of the "Media storage" app and rebooted the device. The album art is still corrupt. I don't know what I still can do.

The audio playing apps I've been using include Winamp, Songbird, Google Play Music and Shuttle Music Player. Each of them showed the corrupt album art the same way.

I'm using Android ICS on an HTC One V.

Answer (score 2):

The problem might not be with your album art, but with your mp3 file. You can try replacing the current album art if any, using a software like Windows Media Player ("WMP") through your computer. All you have to do is to locate the mp3 from your WMP, right click on the current album art and paste a picture. [(More info)](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ph/windows-vista/add-or-change-album-art-in-windows-media-player)

Also you can make your stock music app to update music data as well. More info is available on [HTC support website](https://support.htc.com/en-us/HTC_One/080/000/030).

Then you can paste the audio file using a different name and a in different location. This might do the trick. Or you can [use another apps](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/37656/23379) to update your album info.

Comment: I did what you suggested and embedded the album art in the files, then deleted the folder.jpg file. Now some apps see the right cover art, but others continue to use the corrupted one which must be cached somewhere... I've even changed the album's folder name to make it seem like different files.

Comment: For the apps that do not still use the correct image, clear the cache and restart the phone. You can always use the walkman app as suggested above.

Comment: @Cutter How did it go?

Comment: Thanks for asking. :) I've installed the Walkman app, Album Art Grabber, and AudioTagger. The Walkman app couldn't edit the tags for some reason (the "Edit song info" menu item is grayed out). I've removed then replaced the album art using the two other apps, cleared the "Media Storage" AND my music player's data, and rebooted, but it didn't change anything. The two latter apps see the correct album art by the way. Only the audio players see the corrupt ones. I absolutely don't see what I can try next to get rid of this corrupt album art now.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, the solution was to use a file explorer to remove the cached image from:

```
/Android/data/com.android.providers.media/albumthumbs/
```