# Audio players read "Chromatics" as "The Chromatics" from ID3v2 MP3 tags

Tags: music-player, id3-tag

I've got an album by the band Chromatics in MP3 format with ID3v2 tags. On my computer the band's name appears as "Chromatics" in any audio player (foobar2000, VLC, MP3Tag). On Android, Shuttle Music Player and the default music player display this artist's name as "The Chromatics". Either Android is guessing that it should add the "The" prefix automatically, or there are hidden, incorrect tags somewhere in my files.

The files initially contained ID3v1 tags as well but I've deleted them. I don't know if the error comes from my files or from a database stored by Android. Most importantly I don't know how to fix it. I've already tried deleting the audio files and rebooting, and clearing the data of the "media storage" app and rebooting, but none of this worked.

Comment: Try the [answer provided](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/50288/23379) for your other question. It should solve this problem as well.

Comment: Tag editing applications will show "Chromatics". I suspect these apps look at the actual file while the audio players look at some media library from the OS...

Comment: As suggested there, take the file to your PC and check file properties for "*The* Chromatics"

Comment: As I said I've checked the tags with three different programs on my PC (plus the file properties in Windows Explorer). Everywhere the tags just read "Chromatics".

Comment: Then you can try converting that mp3 file using some basic audio converter, **without copying the tags**. Then copy the converted file to the phone and see if THE comes. If yes, we are looking for an app in your device that changes tags and if not, THE has beed added in a read only mannar to your mp3.

Comment: How did it go..?

Comment: Thanks for asking. I've found the problem; I had just one track by this artist in another album, and it was tagged "The Chromatics". "Chromatics" and "The Chromatics" were probably (rightfully) considered as the same artist, but Android didn't pick the right one out of the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the problem; I had just one track by this artist in another album, and it was tagged "The Chromatics". "Chromatics" and "The Chromatics" were probably (rightfully) considered as the same artist, but Android didn't pick the right one out of the two to display. I've edited this track's artist tag and now every track by this artist appears correctly tagged.