# How do I make the music player display on the lock screen?

Tags: lock-screens, music-player

When I'm listening to music on my Android using Music Player, I want to see what song I'm listening to on my lock screen, and maybe even play/pause and go forward/backward on the playlist, but not change the playlist.

How can I get this kind of a setting? Do I have to write my own app?

Comment: What phone are you using? What Android version?

Comment: Which music player are you using? Some apps don't have this feature, while Google Music/Play Music does.

Comment: The default music player for the Samsung Galaxy S III.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The upgrade to Android 4.3 came from my service provider last week, so I upgraded. Now I can play and pause music from the lock screen!

Answer (score 1):

By default, the stock player has the player controls in Android. Play a song from your stock music player app (the one which was originally included in your mobile) and play a song. When you turn off the screen and get back to the lock screen, you must be able to see the player controls.

You can also try [Sony Walkman](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/35948/23379) which offers a number of features including lock screen controls. You can also use an app like [Simply Lockscreen](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.firezenk.simplylock) to enable music player functionality to your lock screen.

Comment: Nope. I have my music playing from my headphones with no indicator on the lock screen.

Comment: Maybe it depends on the player used. On one of my devices, I use Cubed, which places a "widget" on the lock screen (though a little clumbsy looking).

Answer (score 1):

On my LG:

1. Settings-General-Apps & Notifications-Notifications-Lock Screen-Show All Notifications
2. Settings-General-Apps & Notifications-Notifications-Apps-Music-Categories-Medium (low setting will not work)

Answer (score 0):

On your Andriod phone, when you can't see the music playing, on the lock screen. All you need to do is go to your phone settings and enter 'Apps & Notification' click on the music app, tap on the data usage and then clear your cache.."IT'S DONE"... That's all you need to do. It's pretty simple right?

But you should only do this if you don't care about your playlists anymore, cause as you clear your cache it removes all the playlists you've created from your music app and then your songs will start showing on the lock screen again.

NOTE: please do not clear your data usage, ONLY CLEAR YOUR CACHE because you may lose all your songs.

Answer (score 0):

Tap and hold on the app until you see the 2 section dropbox. It should say/show APPS and WIDGETS. Tap on widgets. You should be seeing the Amazon Music widget. Tap and hold on the screen. You will be able to drag the Amazon control app onto your screen and yes, it does work on locked screens.